# Method that writes code for any color I want

Tags: c#

```
public static void TextColor(string green, string blue, string red)
{
    green = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    blue = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
    red = Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
}
```

Error I get is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ConsoleColor' to 'string'

I'm trying make a method that gets called like this: `TextColor(Green)`, and basically that's going to do: `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green` , obviously i want to do that for all the colors and then call whichever color I want  (Just saves time so I don't have to type: `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.[specific color]` every time).

Comment: It's not really clear what you expect the call to look like - you've shown `TextColor(Green)` which provides only one argument when you've got three parameters. It's also not clear what you expect that `Green` to mean. What would the string value be?

Comment: Perhaps you actually just want three methods, `SetGreenText`, `SetRedText`, `SetBlueText`?

Comment: If you want the user to pass a single argument, then only define a single argument. Then use an if/else or switch statement to determine what the value of the argument was that they passed.

Comment: [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx()) maybe?

Comment: If your parameter is a `string` you could parse the value: `Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), colorString);`.

Comment: I basically want to put Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor[specific color] into string, then when i want to call that method in Main class i type: TextColor(green); . The purpose of that method is to do  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.[any color i want] , and i want to put all the colors into string with that color name.

Comment: Why do you need a method for that? If you're going to pass color every time you call the method and then just do the assignment, then just do the assignment in the main anyway.

Comment: Whole purpose is to practice, i want to write a method that works like that. I want to have bunch of color strings , and then just call TextColor(green), or TextColor(red), which is going to do Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green, or Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. But my point is, it's kind of redundant. Essentially what you're doing is keep a list of strings that corresponds to the values of `ConsoleColor` enum, then every time you want to set the color you just convert that string into the enum and setting it. Why not just simply set the `ConsoleColor` enum value to the foreground color when you want? Writing a method for this is really redundant.

Comment: @Sach If you want to allow the user to type in a color, this method makes a handy way to do that. For example consider the method: `public static void SetForegroundColor (string color) { ConsoleColor newColor; if (ConsoleColor.TryParse(color, true, out newColor)) { Console.ForegroundColor = newColor; } }`. Now we can let the user decide the color: `while (true) { Console.Write("Enter a color: "); SetForegroundColor(Console.ReadLine()); }`

Comment: Rather than using a string, why not just have `using static System.ConsoleColor;`. Then you can change your method parameter to `ConsoleColor`, and *actually* call it as `TextColor(Green)`.

Comment: @RufusL well OK that's one way of doing that, but quite frankly rather than letting the user make a million mistakes by typing to enter, I'll actually present the user with the available options (i.e., Console colors in this situation) and let the user pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parameter is a string you could parse the value:

```
public static void TextColor(string colorString)
{
  Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor) Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), colorString);
}
```

Example:

```
TextColor("Green"); // Sets Console.ForegroundColor to ConsoleColor.Green
TextColor("Blue"); // Sets Console.ForegroundColor to ConsoleColor.Blue
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. You need to cast.

Comment: This works almost the same way i wanted, but i wanted to create bunch of color strings, and each string contains specific  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor[color],  then call it by string TextColor(blue) or any color I want.

Comment: @JackPeeterson: Then I'd avoid using strings. Just use a static using directive so that `Green` means `ConsoleColor.Green`.